# How many writes/second can a single SQL master-slave handle?

Tags: mysql, system-design

I came across this article https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer/blob/master/solutions/system_design/pastebin/README.md which says 4 writes per second should be doable for a single SQL write master-slave. In another article, it is mentioned that 2000 writes per second is too much for a single SQL write master-slave. Not having worked on setting up SQL databases directly, my question is: How can I tell how much can a single write master-slave handle? I would like to understand:

(1) What are the **typical** write QPS that this setup can handle in modern machines? This is for general intuition.

(2) Suppose my application is using this setup for its database. How should I load test the database first to identify write QPS capacity , and then how should I monitor it as there is more usage?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine the exact number of queries you can run on a master/slave system as it depends on a lot of variables.

How powerful is the CPU, is a SSD or HDD used, what exactly are the writes/reads, database version, network connectivity ect.

4 writes/seconds is laughably low, depending on your setup you should be able to consistently do thousands of writes per second.

I would recommend first testing a master/slave system with a test load and to determine if it's feasible for your case from there. If you don't actually have a working system in place and are just wondering if you should start with a master/slave , you can safely start at such, you will most likely not hit bottlenecks related to it anytime soon.